# Link GCP Cloud DNS with Google Domains

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-dns, google-domains

I’ve got my cluster running in GKE with `cert-manager` handling my certs, being validated by “LetsEncrypt”.

`cert-manager` generates new certs every 3 months and publishes the `_acme-challenge` records to **Cloud DNS** in my GCP project, but my domains are handled in **Google Domains**.
So, when there are new challenges records generated, I need to manually copy them from Cloud DNS in GCP over to Google Domains. And that results in some down time on the HTTPS part of my domains.

Is there a way to link Cloud DNS with Google Domains, so that the challenges are published on Google Domains or so that Google Domains can look into Cloud DNS and read the records from there?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by Nameserver record forwarding to Cloud DNS. You must enter the authoritative name servers for Cloud DNS in the name servers section of Google Domains, as opposed to adding them as NS records to the Google Domains managed zone. Please follow [1](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/tutorials/create-domain-tutorial) for more details